# Javascript/JQuery styling - #button:hover stays active after clicking to full-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I know Javascript's full-screen ability is still relatively new, so I'm not sure if this is a bug that has yet to be worked out, if there's a simple solution to the problem, or if I just made a stupid mistake...

I have an input button within a div. When clicked, the input button makes the div full-screen. This input button has a CSS background image, and a hover state that uses the same background image, but changes the background-position (to eliminate the need of multiple images). When the button is clicked again, the div exits full-screen.

The problem comes when the div enters full-screen. The button, which is in a hover state when clicked, stays in the hover state when the div changes to full-screen. The div repositions the button on the screen, to a place where it is no longer under the cursor (like it's supposed to) but for some reason the button still thinks that it should be in the hover state. It is not until I move the cursor back onto and off of the button, that the button will "de-hover" and resume its normal hover/de-hover behavior. What I need is for the button to not remain in the hover state after the div changes to full-screen.

Pieces of simplified code are below, but I left out the RunPrefixMethod function, since it's generic and I don't think necessary to solve this problem. If it is necessary, let me know.

Oh, and I'm using the latest version of Firefox, and haven't tested it in any other browsers yet. I know full screen functionality is limited to more recent browsers, and that there are issues in the ones that do support it. Thanks for any help you can provide.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="fullBox">
    <input type="submit" value="" id="fullbtn" class="btn" onclick="fullscreen();"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#fullBox {
    width:900px;
    height:440px;
    position:absolute;
}
#fullbtn {
    width:44px;
    height:31px;
    background: url(btn_full.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function fullscreen() {
    var e = document.getElementById("fullBox");
    if (RunPrefixMethod(document, "FullScreen") || 
        RunPrefixMethod(document, "IsFullScreen")) {
        RunPrefixMethod(document, "CancelFullScreen");
    }
    else {
        RunPrefixMethod(e, "RequestFullScreen");
    }
}
```

Comment: inside full screen function, you can have one more function with some time-out, which removes the background-position : bottom?

Comment: To eliminate confusion, I have posted a very simplified version of the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkNNa/5/ This code will not work in JSFiddle because they don't support fullscreen functionality, but if you copy and paste the code sections into a document, it will function as I described in my question. To eliminate the need for the image in this example, I simply used a background color instead. As you will see, when you hover over the button, it turns green, but when you click the button and fullscreen is applied, the button stays green rather than going back to red as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="fullBox">
    <input type="submit" value="" onmouseover="this.className='btn hover'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" id="fullbtn" class="btn" onclick="fullscreen();"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#fullBox {
    width:900px;
    height:440px;
    position:absolute;
}
#fullbtn {
    width:44px;
    height:31px;
    background: url(btn_full.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.btn.hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function fullscreen() {
    document.getElementById("fullbtn").className="btn";
    var e = document.getElementById("fullBox");
    if (RunPrefixMethod(document, "FullScreen") || 
        RunPrefixMethod(document, "IsFullScreen")) {
        RunPrefixMethod(document, "CancelFullScreen");
    }
    else {
        RunPrefixMethod(e, "RequestFullScreen");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but this code doesn't solve the problem. To further clarify, I wrote a comment below my question with a JSFiddle with more complete code. It will not function in JSFiddle because they don't allow fullscreen functionality, but all of the code is there for viewing.